# is there any faster way to do this exercise?

Tags: c++

`int function2 (const char * string1)` returning the number of unique digits appearing in the string, e.g. `function2 ("ab512af6kc1") -> 3`.

```
int function2(const char* string1) {
  int zero = 0, one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0,
      seven = 0, eight = 0, nine = 0, counter = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++) {
    if (string1[i] == '0') {
      zero++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '1') {
      one++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '2') {
      two++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '3') {
      three++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '4') {
      four++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '5') {
      five++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '6') {
      six++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '7') {
      seven++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '8') {
      eight++;
    }
    if (string1[i] == '9') {
      nine++;
    }
  }
  if (zero == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (one == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (two == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (three == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (four == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (five == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (six == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (seven == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (eight == 1) {
    counter++;
  }
  if (nine == 1) {
    counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}
```

It's every correct in this code, but it's long a bit. Could someone help me and write SHORTER code? It's the only way that I can measure up to this exercise.

Comment: Have you learned to use arrays and loops yet? What about switch-case? Should "12334" return 3 or 4?  (Your code will return 3.)

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++) {` -- Do not call `strlen` like this as part of the `for` loop construct.  For each iteration, you are calling `strlen`.  Imagine if the string is 100 characters -- that is 10000 iterations being done.

Comment: Consider using the standard library and [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: `function2 ("ab512af6kc1")` should return `4`. The digits are `5` `1` `2` and `6`.

Comment: @xyz9 Do not bother. Programmers are usually paid for the quantity of code written.:)

Comment: @KamilCuk  I think that 1 is not a unique digit in the string.:)

Comment: *Could someone help me and write SHORTER code?* -- You can use `std::unordered_set` and an `isdigit` loop.  Then it becomes 3 or 4 lines of code.

Comment: @KamilCuk no it shouldn't if i have two same numbers it gives me 0, if i had "ab512af6kc" --> return 4.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table collection class to keep track of unique digits.  In this case, `unordered_set` will do just fine.  Don't even bother converting the char to integer.  You're just looking for unique chars between `'0'` and `'9'`.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

size_t getUniqueDigits(const std::string& string1)
{
    std::unordered_set<char> table;
    for (char c : string1)
    {
        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        {
            table.insert(c);
        }
    }
    return table.size();
}
```

A more traditional "C" based solution that doesn't use any std:: collections or objects is to use an array to be that "set"

```
int getUniqueDigits(const char* string1)
{
    int table[10] = {0};
    int count = 0;
    const size_t len = (string1 != nullptr) ? strlen(string1) : 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char c = string1[i];
        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        {
            table[c - '0'] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (char j = '0'; j <= '9'; j++)
    {
        count += table[j];
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: That "traditional 'C' based solution" has far less overhead. I see it as a much better solution than the other.

Comment: A hash table for 10 digits is just complete overkill.

Comment: @BessieTheCow - that depends on what you want to optimize for. Maintainability vs speed. With that being said, both solutions are fairly easy to comprehend - hence both satisfy. If your project is big enough, chances are high you've already paid the price to link in string and set. You might as well use them.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten your code, use an array instead of 10 individual variables:

```
int digits[10] = {0}; // instead of int zero = 0, one = 0, ...
```

To check whether a `char` is a representation of a digit, use `isdigit`:

```
if (isdigit(string1[i])) // instead of if (string1[i] == '0'), if (string1[i] == '1'), ...
```

The only non-trivial part is to convert a `char` to the corresponding `int`:

```
string1[i] - '0'
```

This code subtracts the character code of `0` (usually 48) from the character code of a digit (usually 49 for `1`, 50 for `2`, ..., 57 for `9`). The result is an index to your array of counters.

So, to increase the proper array element, use the following code:

```
digit = string1[i] - '0';
digits[digit]++; // instead of zero++, one++, ...
```

After the code goes over the input string, count the number of digits which appeared once:

```
int counter = 0;
for (digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit)
{
    if (digits[digit] == 1)
        ++counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array instead of 10 variables. Calculate the index in the array by converting the character to an integer.

```
int function2(const char *in) {
   // Array to hold digits occurence counts.
   unsigned digits[10]{};
   // Iterate over the characters in input.
   // Better (auto i : std::string_view(in)) in C++17.
   for (auto i = in; *i; ++i) {
        if (isdigit(*i)) {
            // Increment the proper digit index.
            digits[*i - '0']++;
        }
   }
   int count = 0;
   // Go through digit occurences.
   for (auto i : digits) {
      // If the digit occurred only once.
      if (i == 1) {
         // Increment the count.
         count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an ordinary array as for example in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

size_t unique_digits( const char *s )
{
    unsigned char digits[10] = { 0 };

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( '0' <= *s && *s <= '9' )
        {
            if ( digits[*s - '0'] != 2 ) ++digits[*s - '0'];
        }
    }

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( unsigned char c : digits ) count += c == 1;

    return count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << unique_digits( "ab512af6kc1" ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

Or you can declare the array of the element type `size_t`. In this case the function will look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

size_t unique_digits( const char *s )
{
    size_t digits[10] = { 0 };

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( '0' <= *s && *s <= '9' )
        {
            ++digits[*s - '0'];
        }
    }

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( unsigned char c : digits ) count += c == 1;

    return count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << unique_digits( "ab512af6kc1" ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit to the check ```if ( digits[*s - '0'] != 2 )```?

Comment: @cigien A string can be very big. In this case you have to declare an array with the element type size_t if you want to always increment it.

Comment: That makes sense. So wouldn't it be better to have a size_t array, and avoid the check?

Comment: @cigien This check  is very fast.

Comment: Sure, but it can't be faster than *not* doing the check, right? Or is it somehow better to do the check, and have an unsigned char array?

Comment: @cigien Without the check you always will increment the array.

Comment: oh, is a bool comparison faster than an increment? And fast enough to make up for the cases where both the check and the increment are done?

Comment: @cigien I am sure it is not the case where you should think what is faster.

Comment: can i replace it with something else? " for ( unsigned char c : digits )"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Absolutely, I was just trying to shorten the code, as per the question :) So I was wondering why you chose to do the check? No worries.

Comment: @xyz9 You can use the for loop like for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) count += digits[i] == 1;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow could you tell me the last thing what is going on here? "if (digits[*s - '0'] != 2 ) ++digits[*s - '0'];" how should i interpret it

Comment: @xyz9 There is no any need to increment an element of the array if it is already set to 2 that means that the corresponding digit is not unique.

Comment: digits[*s - '0'] - its array with all elements right? like tab[tab-1]

Comment: @xyz9 *s contains a character like '1', '2' and so on. To convert it to numbers 1, 2, and so on you use the expression *s - '0'. For example the ASCII code of '1' is 49. The ASCII code of '0' is 48. SO to get the index of the array element you can write '1' - '0' that is equivalent to 49 - 48.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have many good solutions.

Here is mine version anyway

```
int function2(const char* string1) {
    int count[10] = {0};
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++)
        int a = (++count[string1[i]-'0']);
        if(a == 1)counter++;
        if(a == 2)counter--;
    return counter;
}
```

I haven't tried it. Hope there is no error

Edit:
I tried it. It seems to work fine now.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem ?

Comment: @counter < 10 The problem is in this condition counter < 10. and in this statement if((++count[string1[i]-'0']) == 1)counter++;

Comment: That is an additional check. If we find 10 character there is no need to continue parsing the string. C language give the && operator the right precedence. The condition should be right. Can you explain better what is the error? have you run my code ?

Comment: According to the question unique digits mean digits that are not repeated in the string.

Comment: @TonyBarletta could you tell me what is happening here? "int a = (++count[string1[i]-'0']);"

Comment: ++x add 1 to x before using it inside a statement. so printf("%d",++x) will print 1 if x is 0 at the beginning. x will become 1 after the printf.
In the line "int a = (++count[...]);" you will first update count[...] with count[...]+1, then it will be stored in a. The index used for count is the ASCII code of the current char (string1[i]) minus the ASCII code of '0'. This difference is the actual index. So for the char '0' we will index 0, for the char '7' we will index 7 and so on.